# Foreach inside Foreach based on column value

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent, model

I have an sql table knowledgebase like so

id , categoryid, title

| id | categoryid | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | apple |
| 2 | 1 | fb |
| 3 | 2 | google |
| 4 | 2 | DB |
| 5 | 3 | Reebok |

In my laravel blade, I am trying to create a tree view to look like the following

```
-1
--apple
--FB
-2
--google
--DB
-3
--Reebok
```

My controller does a basic query and returns the entire table to the view. I am a newbie to laravel so far, I can get a basic table to work like

```
@foreach($knowledgebase as $key => $value)
<tr>
    <td>{!! $knowledgebase ->id !!}</td>
    <td>{!! $knowledgebase ->title!!}</td>
    <td>{!! $knowledgebase ->categoryid !!}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

How would I iterate categroyid column , display first category and all child titles and then move on to the next categoryid.

Update

```
public function show($id) {

    //get article
    $knowledgebase = \App\Models\Knowledgebase::Where('knowledgebase_slug', request('knowledgebase_slug'))->first();

return view('knowledgebase', compact('knowledgebase'));

}
```

Comment: Can you show your controller as well?

Comment: Your model and migration please, maybe you have to self join the model/table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, I managed to solve this by adding a function children in my model. So in my Model added

```
public function children(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Knowledgebase', 'categoryid');
}
```

After this, I simply called it as a foreach inside my foreach

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<li><a href="#">{{ $category->title}}</a></li>
@if($category->children)
@foreach($category->children as $child)
<ul>
<li class="pl-3"><a href="#"> {{ $child->title}} </a></li>
</ul>
@endforeach
@endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You will need to retrieve in controller the categories before ($categories)
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $category->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $category->title}}</td>
      <td>{{ $category->categoryid }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Its the same table. I am not sure how to retreive categories seperately when its all in the same table.